# Redirecting the url after login (react js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, formik, yup

I'm a react js beginner. I got stuck in this problem for many days. I don't know how to redirect to path /users when the login is successful (no validation errors). If anything not clear, please tell me. It's my first time to ask question on stackoverflow. Please help :(

//app.js

```
import React from "react"
import ValidationLog from "./ValidationLog"
import PostList from "./PostList"
import  {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Switch,Redirect}  from "react-router-dom"

function App() {
  

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={ValidationLog}></Route>
          <Route path="/users" component={PostList}></Route>
        </Switch>
          
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
  
}
export default App
```

//ValidationLog.js

```
import React from "react"
import {Formik} from "formik"
import * as Yup from "yup"
import  {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Switch,Redirect}  from "react-router-dom"


const ValidationLog = () => (
    
    <Formik 
    
     initialValues = {{email: "", password: ""}}
     onSubmit = {(values,{ setSubmitting}) => {
         setTimeout(() => {
            <Redirect to="/users" /> 
            
         }, 500);
     }}
     
     validationSchema = {Yup.object().shape({
        email: Yup.string()
            .email()
            .required("Required"),
        password: Yup.string()
            .required("No password provided")
            .min(8,"Password has to be at least 8 characters.")
     })
            
    }
    >
        {props => {
            const {
                values,
                touched,
                errors,
                isSubmitting,
                handleChange,
                handleBlur,
                handleSubmit
            } = props

            
            
            
            return (
                    
                    <div>
                        

                        <form autoComplete = "off" onSubmit = {handleSubmit}>
                            <h2 style={{fontSize: 22}}>Login to view our user pool</h2>
                            <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
                            <input type="text" value={values.email} name="email" onChange={handleChange} onBlur={handleBlur} placeholder="Enter your email" className={errors.email && touched.email && "error"}/>
                            {errors.email && touched.email && (<div className="input-feedback">{errors.email}</div>)}
                            <label htmlFor="email">Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" value={values.password} name="password" onChange={handleChange} onBlur={handleBlur} placeholder="Enter your password" className={errors.password && touched.password && "error"}/>
                            {errors.password && touched.password && (<div className="input-feedback">{errors.password}</div>)}
                            <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>Login</button>
                            
                        </form>

                    </div>
            )
        }}
    </Formik>
)


export default ValidationLog
```

The following is what I tried. I tried to add a <Redirect to /users/> in ValidationLog.js

```
 onSubmit = {(values,{ setSubmitting}) => {
         setTimeout(() => {
            <Redirect to="/users" /> 
            
         }, 500);
     }}
```

I also tried to set a variable islogin in ValidationLog.js and import in app.js when there is no validation errors but islogin is always false in app.js.

//ValidationLog.js

```
export let islogin = false
onSubmit = {(values,{ setSubmitting}) => {
         setTimeout(() => {
            islogin = true
            console.log(`Logged in ${islogin}`)
         }, 500);
     }}
```

//app.js

```
import ValidationLog,{islogin} from "./ValidationLog"

<Route exact path="/">
  {islogin ? <Redirect to="/users" /> : null}
</Route>
```

Comment: You can redirect by assigning a new value to the global window.location value. `location = '/users/'`. You can do that in your login callback function. That will tell the browser to reload the page, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<Redirect ... />` is a JSX-Construct to create a component at this position. By itself this does not do anything in imperative code-paths like your `onSubmit` handler.

What you are looking for is an imperative function that you can call outside a React-Tree. Like from the `useHistory` hook from react-router.

```js
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

...

const history = useHistory();

...

  onSubmit={() => history.push("/home")}
```

More specifically for your example:

```
const ValidationLog = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  return (
    
    <Formik 
    
     initialValues = {{email: "", password: ""}}
     onSubmit = {(values,{ setSubmitting}) => {
         setTimeout(() => {
            history.push(...)
            
         }, 500);
     }}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I'm not sure about what you mean. You mean to create another function in another file using useHistory() ? How can I link these two files ?

Comment: No new file is needed, just change your `ValidationLog` component. I will reflect possible changes in the answer

Comment: Originally the <div></div> tag is in my return.Where should I move the part to? Sorry I'm really new to react.js.

Comment: No offense, but you probably should read up on JavaScript and then React. Because some of the concepts do not relate to your original question. 

As to answer your direct question: `ValidationLog` is an arrow function that implicitly returns (because it has no body). I changed that to explicit return because we need the hook. Thats why you have "two returns". The other return you mentioned is in another arrow function (the render function of Formik).

Comment: Your comment really helps me to understand some of the concepts that I didn't learn well.I didn't notice that there is a difference between arrow function with {}. Thanks again for your kindness! Happy coding!

Comment: Glad I could be of help, dont forget to mark the anwer you find most fitting for your question as the accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using withRouter

Import withRouter from react-router-dom and enclose your component with withRouter in the export.

You can then navigate using this.props.history.push("/newurl")

```
import React from "react"
import {Formik} from "formik"
import * as Yup from "yup"
// import withRouter
import  {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Switch,Redirect,withRouter}  from "react-router-dom"


const ValidationLog = (props) => (

<Formik 

 initialValues = {{email: "", password: ""}}
 onSubmit = {(values,{ setSubmitting}) => {
     setTimeout(() => {
        // this redirects to /users, make sure you get the import withRouter (check the last export line)
        props.history.push("/users");
        
     }, 500);
 }}
 
 validationSchema = {Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string()
        .email()
        .required("Required"),
    password: Yup.string()
        .required("No password provided")
        .min(8,"Password has to be at least 8 characters.")
 })
        
}
>
    {props => {
        const {
            values,
            touched,
            errors,
            isSubmitting,
            handleChange,
            handleBlur,
            handleSubmit
        } = props

        
        
        
        return (
                
                <div>
                    

                    <form autoComplete = "off" onSubmit = {handleSubmit}>
                        <h2 style={{fontSize: 22}}>Login to view our user pool</h2>
                        <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
                        <input type="text" value={values.email} name="email" onChange={handleChange} onBlur={handleBlur} placeholder="Enter your email" className={errors.email && touched.email && "error"}/>
                        {errors.email && touched.email && (<div className="input-feedback">{errors.email}</div>)}
                        <label htmlFor="email">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" value={values.password} name="password" onChange={handleChange} onBlur={handleBlur} placeholder="Enter your password" className={errors.password && touched.password && "error"}/>
                        {errors.password && touched.password && (<div className="input-feedback">{errors.password}</div>)}
                        <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>Login</button>
                        
                    </form>

                </div>
        )
    }}
</Formik>
)

// changes
export default withRouter(ValidationLog)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it seems that there will be an error saying that props is undefined.

Comment: Oops i forgot taking props as a parameter for the component, I've made the changes (const ValidationLog = (props) =>  ) required, it should work now.

Comment: Omg it works thank u so much, but could you please briefly explain it how it works? I mean why doesn't <redirect> works? Also when to use withRouter?

Comment: <Redirect> only works inside a <Switch> block. When you enclose your component with withRouter you get the history object in the props, which you can then use to navigate

Comment: I see! You mean when enclosing the component with withRouter, the props will become the history path from app.js right? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`<Redirect>` component approach here:

Use a state variable in your component

```
const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);
```

On submitting, if conditions for redirect are met set this state variable to `true`

```
setSubmitted(true);
```

In your component JSX, place the `<Redirect to="/users" />` conditionally depending on that state variable

```
return <Fragment>
{ submitted 
? <Redirect to="/users" />
: <MyComponent ...> }
</Fragment>
```

**Note**

If you prefer to avoid this *ternary operator syntax* for whaterver reason, you could solve this with variables in the component logic before the return. Might be cleaner depending on the complexity of the component.